# For each Pandas group remove rows based on a column matching with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) where they share two common columns `PID` and `event_date`.

`df1` is indexed by `PID` and each `PID` has multiple rows:

| PID | Ses_ID | Var_1 | event_date | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 002 003 | 0.7 0.8 0.9 | 2013-09-05 2013-09-06 2013-09-07 | 0 1 0 |
| 002 | 009 004 004 005 005 006 007 | 0.1 0.8 0.8 0.7 0.8 0.2 0.8 | 2014-09-05 2014-09-06 2014-09-07 2014-10-05 2014-10-15 2014-10-25 2014-11-05 | 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 |

In `df2` each `PID` only has one row:

| PID | event_date |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2013-09-06 |
| 002 | 2014-10-01 |

In `df1` for each `PID` I want to only keep the rows where their `event_date`s are before the corresponding `event_date`in `df2` indexed by the same `PID`. So the above `df1` example would become:

| PID | Ses_ID | Var_1 | event_date | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 0.7 | 2013-09-05 | 0 |
| 002 | 009 004 004 | 0.1 0.8 0.8 | 2014-09-05 2014-09-06 2014-09-07 | 0 0 0 |

I have attempted to achieve this with the code below but came to `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` error. It is definitely not efficient either and I have a very large scale `df1` to iterate over. Any suggestions that this can be in a less time-consuming way pls? Thanks!

```
for pid, _ in df1.groupby(level=0):
    df1.loc[pid] = df1.loc[pid][df1.loc[pid]['event_date'] < df2.loc[pid]['event_date']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` to combine two dataframes, and then compare event_date in two columns.

Try this:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)
df_merge = df_merge.loc[df_merge.event_date_x < df_merge.event_date_y]
```

`left_index` and `right_index` mean to combine dataframes based on their indices.

Comment: Thanks @Crystal. I have opted to achieve this in a for-loop and appending the relevant fields of each sub dataframe to a list of dicts, which I think is more suitable for my case.